# Data download failed with package lodown

Tags: r, survey

I'm having issues importing the data for the American Housing Survey (AHS) using the package lodown.

Here's what I have done:

```
# Download all relevant files needed (from http://asdfree.com/american-housing-survey-ahs.html)
install.packages( "devtools" , repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/" )
library(devtools)
install_github( "ajdamico/lodown" , dependencies = TRUE )

load.packs <- c("survey",      "lodown",       "convey",       "srvyr")
install.packs <- load.packs[!load.packs %in% installed.packages()]
for(lib in install.packs) install.packages(lib, dependencies = TRUE)
sapply(load.packs, require, character=TRUE)

#provided download call on website:
library(lodown)
lodown( "ahs" , output_dir = file.path( path.expand( "~" ) , "AHS" ) )
```

Then I get the following output with the error

```
trying URL 'https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/ahs/data.All.html'
Content type 'text/html' length unknown
downloaded 169 KB

trying URL 'https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/ahs/data.2017.html'
Content type 'text/html' length unknown
downloaded 154 KB
```

**Note: error in download and 403 forbidden**

```
trying URL 'https://www.census.gov//programs-surveys/ahs/data/2017/ahs-2017-public-use-file--puf-.html" onclick="linkClick(this, 'Census List Component');" class="uscb-list-item '
Error in download.file(paste0("https://www.census.gov/", puf.lines), tf,  : 
  cannot open URL 'https://www.census.gov//programs-surveys/ahs/data/2017/ahs-2017-public-use-file--puf-.html" onclick="linkClick(this, 'Census List Component');" class="uscb-list-item '
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(paste0("https://www.census.gov/", puf.lines), tf,  :
  cannot open URL 'https://www.census.gov//programs-surveys/ahs/data/2017/ahs-2017-public-use-file--puf-.html" onclick="linkClick(this, 'Census List Component');" class="uscb-list-item ': HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'
```

Further, I can't tell if it's working  even with what is supposedly downloaded because there's nothing new in the location it should be...

```
ahs_df <- 
    readRDS( 
        file.path( path.expand( "~" ) , "AHS" , 
            "2013/national_v1.2/newhouse_repwgt.rds" 
        ) 
    )
```

returns

```
Error in gzfile(file, "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(file, "rb") :
cannot open compressed file 'C:/Users/.../AHS/2013/national_v1.2/newhouse_repwgt.rds', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

How can I verify if data is downloading here? Has anyone had this issue? I've seen other stack posts on other data, but I've not seen this problem before.

Answer (score 1):

i do need to fix that, but it's not a priority.  if you'd like to submit a pull request with the patch, please do!

in addition to the code in the `lodown` package, there's older code in the archive:

https://github.com/ajdamico/asdfree/tree/archive

https://usgsd.blogspot.com/2014/06/analyze-american-housing-survey-ahs.html

sorry i'm unable to maintain that code at the moment

Comment: What exactly would I have to change in the code to get this working? I'm not against submitting a patch I just don't know where to start (I haven't done it before).